# Оптимизация обновления в партиционированную PostgreSQL-таблицу с SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, оптимизация, sqlalchemy, postgresql

Есть PostgreSQL 9.1 с [партиционированной таблицей](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-partitioning.html), очень упрощенно — вот такой:

```
-- Базовая таблица, сама по себе записей не содержит
CREATE TABLE entries (
    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    started TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    stopped TIMESTAMPTZ DEFAULT NULL,
    counter BIGINT DEFAULT 0
);

-- Архивные данные, раздел за 2012 год (есть и другие года)
CREATE TABLE entries_2012 (
    CHECK (stopped IS NOT NULL),
    CHECK (started >= DATE '2012-01-01' AND started < DATE '2013-01-01')
) INHERITS (sessions);

-- Активные данные
CREATE TABLE entries_active (
    CHECK (stopped IS NULL),
) INHERITS (sessions);

-- И есть триггеры на INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE, которые раскладывают
-- и перемещают ряды между дочерними таблицами sessions, согласно
-- ограничениям.
```

С ней работает SQLAlchemy 0.5.8 (можно, при острой необходимости, обновить), как-то так:

```
# Модель минималистична, проектирование идет со стороны БД, а не кода
class Entry(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'entries'
    __table_args__ = {'autoload': True}

# Находим нужную запись. В реальном коде условия довольно сложные
# и составляются динамически.
e = session.query(Entry).filter(...).first()
if e is not None:
    # Делаем разные изменения. Для примера обойдемся одним простым.
    e.counter = new_counter_value
    # Сохраняем.
    session.add(e)
    session.commit()
```

Это отправляет в БД запрос вида:

```
UPDATE entries SET counter = 12345 WHERE id = 321
```

Что вполне правильно, но требует поиска ряда по первичному ключу во всех разделах таблицы (`entries_2005`, `entries_2006`, ..., `entries_2012`, `entries_active`), т.е. выполняется относительно медленно.

В большинстве случаев, но не всегда, обновляются данные в `entries_active`. Соответственно, хочется как-то оптимизировать ситуацию.

При этом просто сделать отдельную модель `ActiveEntry` для таблицы `entries_active` нельзя — за время работы соседняя транзакция может поменять значение столбца `stopped`, переведя ряд в другую таблицу.

Оптимальным кажется добавить в `WHERE` SQL-запроса еще `AND stopped IS NULL`, посмотреть на число обновленных рядов, если их 0 — повторно выдать запрос без дополнительного условия. Но как это сделать с SQLAlchemy я, честно говоря, не представляю.

Буду благодарен за любые идеи.

Comment: А raw query она не дает выполнить? Очевидно тут ORM только мешает...
Либо сформировать условие для update и скормить этот raw-запрос или создать хранимую процедуру для update...

Comment: Давать-то дает, но ORM тут мне полезен всем, кроме того, как он конструирует WHERE-часть UPDATE-запроса. Что я и хочу как-то поменять. По крайней мере, вытянуть из объекта изменившиеся поля.

Comment: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#multiple-table-updates
По-моему то, что нужно. Т.е. надо не искать записи по фильтру и их апдейтить. а сразу апдейт строить...

Comment: Дело в том, что я не только апдейт строю, и строю его не в одном месте. Поэтому `entries.update().values({...})` не решает сути проблемы.

Выбранный из базы `e = session.query(Entry)....` путешествует по куче функций-обработчиков (собственно, поэтому и используется ORM), которые смотрят на текущие значения и, в ряде случаев, их меняют.

И вот что они там в итоге наменяли — если никто не бросил исключения — будет положено в БД в результате `session.commit()`.

Comment: Там не просто ``update().values(...)``, там ``update().values(...).where(...).where(...)``. Суть проблемы решаеют вот эти where. Соответвенно надо их задавать по партиционным ключам чтоб апдейт был по одной необходимой таблице, без скана по всем. 

Если у вас в выборке, которую дает filter есть записи из разных физических таблиц, т.е. весь набор фильтруемых записей не привязать к одной таблице (одному значению партиционных ключей), то update в любом случае будет идти по всем таблицам. Тут вопрос не в "скл-алхимии", а в архитектуре приложения, которая не сможет эффективно работать с базой...

Comment: Я бы тащил эти ключи где только мог за собой во все функции и дописывал их в where условия там где идут update'ы, insert'ы, delete'ы... ну и надо как-то отделять записи из разных физ таблиц, чтоб они не попадали в выборки над которыми потом манипуляции проходят... тогда будет четкая гарантия, что фича с парт. таблицами помогает, а не мешает...

Answer (score 2):

Выглядит сомнительным выигрыш в партициях если у вас поиск идет только по ключу (`id`). imho, в условия нужно всегда писать дополнительно фильтр по дате (`started`, `stopped`), тогда поиска записи по ненужным таблицам не будет и получится существенный выигрыш в скорости. Точно подскажет план конечно, но судя по описанию в документации именно так надо действовать.

Comment: По `id` идет обновление — так SQLAlchemy себя ведет, когда сохраняет объект-модель (и я, увы, не знаю как это поменять, кроме переизобретением всей ORM-части SA). Выборка же (`e = session.query(Entry).filter(...)`) как раз использует партиционирование по полной, без него бы там все залегло.

Т.е. и суть вопроса в том, что там, где я влияю на условия во `WHERE` — все в порядке. А где не знаю как влиять — проблемы.